# Taking OSX+Dropbox like screenshots in Windows?

Tags: windows, screenshot

For a long time, I have been using OSX. Here, I can take screenshots with cmd+shift+4, where I select a part of my screen. Then it is automatically uploaded to Dropbox, and I get it auto-pasted.

Cut in short, I can send specific screenshots in less than 3 seconds.

How can I do something similar in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there were many tools, that could solve my task.

After trying them all, [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html) turned out to be the best tool, by far.

Fast & good auto upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Dropbox on Windows & it works the same. You just have to configure Dropbox to automatically sync the screenshots. And Dropbox configures it automatically first time you take a screenshot on Windows.

Comment: You mean Print Screen? I don't know of a 'screenshot' function in the sense of OSX's, the snipping tool does not save unless you tell it to, and print screen doesn't save to anything.

Comment: On Windows, if you go to Dropbox>Preferences>Import & enable the "Share screenshots using Dropbox" option, the PrintScreen option would work with Dropbox on Windows too. I use it all the time.